# Updating to macOS High Sierra Download doesn't finish

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra

I am trying to updating my macOS Sierra to macOS High Sierra through official installer package from AppStore. The installer started downloading the macOS High Sierra It `almost` downloaded the OS but its stuck on `About one minute remaining`

I cancelled this after 3-4 hours after stuck at this point. And again downloaded from start. It again stuck at the same point.

I have macBookPro mid-2012 and according to apple MacBook Pro 2010 and later are compatible for macOS High Sierra update.

What can be the possible issue and solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given the context of your question, it's unclear if you re-downloaded the installer from the App Store after the first failure or if you ran the upgrade application again. Yes, your computer is supported for the High Sierra update. I have a few suggestions:

- Delete the upgrade application (go to the Finder and delete it).
- Re-download the upgrade application from the App Store.
- Run the application again.

If the problem persists, the solution will probably involve something more drastic. If you have an available flash drive, [try making a bootable flash drive installer](https://www.macworld.com/article/3204672/macs/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-high-sierra-beta-installer-drive.html). Restart and hold **(Option)** and select the bootable USB disk and hit enter. Proceed through the install process. Notify us of the result and we'll proceed from there :)

Good luck ;)

Comment: I just ran the installer again. I try re-download the installer. and will be back if it solves my issue. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Normal delay is expected, maybe the server is busy or your OS is searching/installing something that is resource-intensive. Is it finished now ?